# Fixed points of $\sin(\cos x) $over the interval $[0,\pi/2].$

Tags: real-analysis

Which of the following statements is/are true?

$A.$ $\sin(\cos x)=x$ has exactly one root in $[0,\pi/2]$

$B.$ $\cos(\sin x)=x$ has exactly one root in $[0,\pi/2]$

$C.$ Both $A$ and $B$ are true.

$D.$ Both $A$ and $B$ are false.

I tried as $\cos(\sin x):[0,\pi/2]\rightarrow [0,\pi/2]$ and $|(\cos(\sin x))'|=|\sin(\sin x) \cos x|<1$
 so it has unique fixed point. But i am confused about fixed points of $\sin(\cos x).$ Please tell me about uniqueness of fixed points of $\sin(\cos x).$ Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked at monotonicity?

Comment: If $x=\cos\sin x$ then with $y=\sin x$ also $y=\sin\cos y$ and vice versa.

Comment: I guess a look at [a graph](https://www.desmos.com/screenshot/oixxy6y3os) would make this quite an easy problem. You could then write down a proof based on the intermediate and mean value theorems. If it's just a quite multiple choice quiz, I'd think the way to go is visually, though.

Comment: Is $sin(cosx)$ monotone?

Comment: $(sin(cosx)')=-cos(cosx)sinx,x\in [0,\pi/2]$

Comment: The two pieces for Banach's fixed point theorem are present and correct for the first function. Please tell us where you can not do the same for the second function.

Comment: in second derivative becomes $1$ at $\pi/2$

Comment: @DanielFischer Its decreasing function and hence unique fixed point?? Am i correct?

Comment: That shows it has _at most_ one fixed point in $[0,\pi/2]$. The existence follows e.g. from the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Yes i know that if $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [a,b]$ is continuous then at least one fixed point. Thanks a lot...

Comment: If you write it in solution column then i think it will be beneficial to other one also...Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

To seek solution of sin(cos$x$)$=x$ in $[0,π/2]$, take $f(x)=sin(cosx)$ ans notice that its graph originates at the point $(0,sin$1$)$ and ends at $(π/2,0)$ on X-axis. Moreover, $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing in $[0,π/2]$ as $f'(x)<0$ therein, hence it will intersect the oblique line $y=x$ exactly once in $[0,π/2]$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property:
STEP1: Find the range of the function.
Suppose it comes out to be $[a,b]$
STEP2: Then find $f(a).f(b)$.
STEP3:. If it comes out to be negative(Think precisely). Then the function will have at least one solution in $[a,b]$

I'd go with options A,B &C.
I'll be glad if you'll do it yourself. Otherwise I will post an image of the solution. Try yourself first...

Answer (score 0):

By the intermediate value theorem there is at least one root (since 0 < sin(cos(0)) and 1 > sin(cos(1))). Since the derivative of sin(cos($x$)) is less than one everywhere we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to conclude that this is the only root.